# Get element's index in selector of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of what are essential dropdown lists on a page. Each list has a heading. When the heading is clicked, the list's height will transition from 0 to whatever the height of the list is in pixels; this animates to make the list grow into position.

Because of restrictions in CSS, I can not transition a height to `auto`. I must transition to a height with a numerical value. Because the height if each list is different, my work around for this is as follows:

1. When page loads, all lists are open
2. Grab the height of each list in pixels, and put it into the array `heights`
3. Set each list's height to 0, to hide them.
4. When a list's heading is clicked, transition it to the height stored in the array

The problem I'm having is trying to associate the index of a number in `heights` with the index of the div hat has been clicked on the page. Here is a sample of 2 lists.

```
<div id="awards">
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <h1>Alien 3</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>Nominated</h2><hr>
                <p>Hugo Award for Best Dramatic Presentation</p>
                <p>Saturn Award for Best Director</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Se7en</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>Won</h2><hr>
                <p>Fantasporto for Best Film</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
```

And the click event's jQuery:

```
$('#awards h1').click(function () {

    var indexPos = $(this).index('#awards .content div div'); //get index of clicked element out of all '#awards .content div div's (the lists)

    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {

        $('#awards .content div div').index(indexPos).css('height', heights[indexPos]);

    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {

        $('#awards .content div div').index(indexPos).css('height', '0');

    }

    $(this).toggleClass('open');

});
```

and for good measure, here is how the array is being created when the document loads:

```
var heights = [];

$('#awards .content div div').each(function(index, element) {
        heights.push($(this).height());
});

$('#awards .content div div').css('height','0');
```

So, what am I missing? when I check the value of indexPos after setting it, it's -1, aka not found. I might have a misunderstanding of how `.index()` works, but how do I fix it?

Comment: jQuery UI has [`switchClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) that performs animation, perhaps you could use that?

Comment: why don't you just toggle the display to show/hide the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using the height like that is the best idea, you can toggle the display property to hide/display the element.

But if you still want to use height, instead of an array try using the data property like

```
$('#awards h1').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.next();

    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $div.height($div.data('height'));
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $div.height(0);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('open');

});


$('#awards .content div div').each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height())
}).height(0);
```

---

I don't know the exact requirement, but it can be simplified as

```js
$('#awards h1').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
#awards h1 + div {
  display: none;
}
#awards h1.open {
  color: green;
}
#awards h1.open + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awards">
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <h1>Alien 3</h1>
      <div>
        <h2>Nominated</h2>
        <hr/>
        <p>Hugo Award for Best Dramatic Presentation</p>
        <p>Saturn Award for Best Director</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Se7en</h1>
      <div>
        <h2>Won</h2>
        <hr/>
        <p>Fantasporto for Best Film</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Your original solution of storing the heights in the `.data` attributes worked perfectly, I had no idea they even existed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GtwoK why can't you use the second solution? is there a different requirement?

Comment: The second solution is how I originally had it running. I decided it looked too static to just have a long list of things "appear" out of nowhere, which is why I chose to animate the height.